# Text coloring on matching words

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I am new to Eclipse RCP and I want to create text editor where if i type something like `MyString obj` the. Typing `MyString` , text will be coloured. Assuming that I have an `array` of such words which contains `MyString`. Kindly suggest me how can I achieve this task other than Xtext framework. If possible, please provide me sample working code.

Comment: Colour it where? In a text editor? in an SWT control? in a tree? a table? ....

Comment: Something like opening any file in Eclipse. Like in test.java , if we type String , String will be coloured and bold but for now I need only coloring part. Preferably, text editor is needed however if using swt control ,if editor can be achieved, please suggest.

Comment: The answer is different for each option so you must decide where you want to do this. Text editors provide very extensive (but very complicated) support for this. StyledText controls can also do colours as can table and trees. You really need to do a lot more research on this because an answer is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What if I make SWT Text as editor ? I know coloring part is bit complex without use of xText. Is there any step by step document of xText which I can use in Text Editor ?

Comment: You can create your own editor with syntax highlighting also via [Eclipse TM4E - TextMate support in the Eclipse IDE](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.tm4e), even without writing Java code for that.

Comment: Howlger @ appreciated your comments but I want to write syntax highlighting logic however I'll look into the given link.

Comment: I have found one link which highlights text on search button. Similarly what if I make text box as editor and use key event listeners ? Link :  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SearchStyleText.htm

Comment: I think StyledText is something workaround of editor.

Comment: The New Plug-in Project wizard has two example templates which cover this - the 'Editor contribution for XML' creates a simple XML editor with colouring. The 'Textual editor relying on Generic Editor' uses the newer generic editor for highlighting.